# Given a users UID can I access his profile info?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I know that I can save user info to his [profile with firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users). But I am wondering if I am able to get this same info when all I have is a UID?

As I understand it I can only do this to get the info:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser.displayName...
```

It seems like If I want to be able to fetch other users info I would have to keep a copy of their data in a users node.

**Am I correct? Or can I access their profile info withought having to keep a copy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use firebase authentication, then you can retrieve the current user info. So, if currently user X is logged in and he is authenticated, you can retrieve the following info about him:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
  // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
  // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  // ...
}
```

If you want to retrieve information about other users, then in that case you need to use firebase database:

```
users
  userId (firebase authentication)
    name : user X
  userId
    name : user Y
```

Comment: If I have to keep a copy of all data would it not be more efficient (in terms of cost, and speed performance) to not user firebases specific profile storage spot? since I can fetch from that users node? Or am I wrong?

Comment: when a user registers, and you add him to the firebase authentication, the data and the password of the user is secured there. When you add the users in the firebase database, you shouldn't add the password there. So, actually both are needed. If you need a list of users in your app then you need the database. If you want authentication and to be able to easily use sign in providers then you need firebase authentication.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but I am wondering if I should for example keep a copy of all profileImages in fire auth... Is it as I said before more efficient when it comes to retrieval?

Comment: In Auth you would have imageurl. You can store the image in the Firebase storage and keep the url in auth. Both are needed and it won't affect speed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the reason you need this data, you can actually get access to an auth user by using the `firebase-admin` package.

inside of your firebase function - or node.js backend - (this is only for backend node.js functions, not for front-end), you can get the user by doing the following:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const authUser = await admin.auth().getUser(uid);

authUser = authUser.toJSON(); // Optional
```

You can read more about retrieving user data  [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)

If you want to load in multiple users at once, you can easily use the `getUsers` function and it's also possible to load in the user based on other information like email:

```
getUser(uid)
getUserByEmail(email)
getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
```